# Javascript Associative Array to return names associated with characteristic

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, associative

I am trying to write code where I have an input box and if I were to type in "A" I would get the names of all the students in my array who have earned "A" grades. I feel I am getting close but I just can't quite figure out what I need to do to make this code function. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Javascript </title>


<script>
var students = [
 {name:"Lina",grade:"F"},
 {name:"Fredrik",grade:"D"},
 {name:"Sara",grade:"C"},
 {name:"Lucia",grade:"B"},
 {name:"Hans",grade:"A"},
 {name:"Jonathan", grade: "A"}
]

gradesByLetter = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'].map(function(letter){
return students.filter(function(student){
 return student.grade == letter;
 });
});

gradesByLetter.forEach(function(list){
list.forEach(function(student){
   document.getElementById(student.grade).innerHTML += "<li>" + student.name +      " (" + student.grade + ")"
});
});


f1.addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
evt.preventDefault(); //ignore this for now but this will stop the error
studentList.innerHTML += "<li>" + studentName.value + " (" + grade.value + ")"
});


</script>
</head>


<body>
<h1>Min Rubik</h1>
<form id="f1">
    <input type="text" id="studentName" placeholder="Student Name">
    <input type="text" id="grade" placeholder="Grade">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
<h2>Students:</h2>
<ul id="studentList">
    <ol id="A"></ol>
    <ol id="B"></ol>
    <ol id="C"></ol>
    <ol id="D"></ol>
    <ol id="F"></ol>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is not constructive. You are asking us to do your homework for you and there is not much apparent effort here.

Comment: I just started learning this stuff last week and have put seemingly endless hours into this. I'm sorry if this doesn't look like "much apparent effort" but I have been slaving away trying to understand this.

Comment: I apologize for assuming you put no effort into the project. I have posted a solution that does what you asked for. Please mark it as the accepted answer if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Your main problem is that you try to attach an event handler to the element with ID `f1` before that element appears in your DOM.  Put your script at the end of the body, not before it.  Also, generally you should use `document.getElementById()` rather than assume that a global variable with the element's ID will exist.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer, if you leave grade empty it will show all students.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Min Rubik</h1>
<form id="f1">
    <input type="text" id="studentName" placeholder="Student Name">
    <input type="text" id="grade" placeholder="Grade">
    <input type="button" id="click_me" value="Add">
</form>
<h2>Students:</h2>
<ul id="studentList">
</ul>

<script>

var students = [
    {name:"Lina",grade:"F"},
    {name:"Fredrik",grade:"D"},
    {name:"Sara",grade:"C"},
    {name:"Lucia",grade:"B"},
    {name:"Hans",grade:"A"},
    {name:"Jonathan", grade: "A"}
];

function clickHandler() {
document.getElementById("studentList").innerHTML = "";
students.forEach(function(student) {
    if ((student.grade == document.getElementById("grade").value || document.getElementById("grade").value == "") &&
        (student.name.toLowerCase() == document.getElementById("studentName").value.toLowerCase() || document.getElementById("studentName").value == "")) {
        document.getElementById("studentList").innerHTML += "<li>" + student.name + " (" + student.grade + ")"
    }
});
}

document.getElementById("click_me").addEventListener('click',clickHandler);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suppose it's an answer, but expecting the OP to play "spot the difference" isn't on.

Comment: I _explained_ the source of his problem.  Take it from me, answers that have nothing but code and no explanation are frowned upon here.